# Default value as Global const vs. Function return value

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, constants, default-value

In the book Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup in section 8.6.2 Global initialization, it is recommended to define default values (e.g. for date in a calendar) as follows:

```
const Date& default_date()
{
  static const Date dd(1970,1,1);
  return dd;
}
```

How does this method compare to simply having a global constant as follows?

```
static const Date dd(1970,1,1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default_date` function is declared with external [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) which means it can be used from any [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which have a suitable declaration.

The global variable have internal linkage, and thus can only be used in the translation unit it's defined in.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

https://godbolt.org/z/Y6Dhbz

From purely a performance POV, the clear winners are:

Declaring as static const in a header file

```cpp
static const Date dd(1970,1,1);
```

Using a constexpr

```cpp
constexpr Date dd(1970,1,1);
```

Returning the default from an inline method.

```cpp
inline Date default_date()
{
  return Date(1970,1,1);
}
```

> How does this method compare to simply having a global constant as follows?

*IF* the method is compiled within the same compilation unit, then basically there is no difference. If however the default_date is extern, then you will incur a few extra loads. Personally, I'd just recommend using constexpr.